# The relation between $b \bmod a$ and the group of all bijective maps from $\mathbb{ℤ}$ to $\mathbb{ℤ}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that $a$ divides $b$ if and only if $s^{b}$ commutes with each $g$ in $G$ that commutes with $s^{a}$, where $G$ is the group of all bijective maps from $\mathbb{ℤ}$ to $\mathbb{ℤ}$.
The only if part is easy to show, but I don't know how to show the if part.

Comment: What is $s^b$ and $s^a$?

Comment: s is the successor function and $ s^{n} $ is s applied n times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g \colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ be the bijection which fixes $a\mathbb{Z}$, and cyclically permutes the elements between $ka$ and $(k+1)a$. For example, with $a = 4$, we would have 
$$g(0) = 0, g(1) = 2, g(2) = 3, g(3) = 1, g(4) = 4$$
and so on. Then $g$ clearly satisfies $g(z) + a = g(z+a)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, so we must have $g(z) + b = g(z+b)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $$g((a+1)b) = g(ab) + b = ab+b = (a+1)b $$
But the only elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ which are fixed by $g$ are multiples of $a$, and $\gcd(a+1, a) = 1$, so $a$ must divide $b$.

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way,did you look at any reference when you worked on this ? Because I want to know what to do if I have this type of problems next time.

Comment: @Minus22: glad I could help! I'm afraid not. My thought process went something like this: I wanted to come up with a bijection of $\mathbb{Z}$ to itself which fixed only elements of $a\mathbb{Z}$, so that I could make this kind of argument. Cyclically permuting the elements in between meshed nicely with the requirement of commuting with $s^{a}$, and felt like the most natural thing to do. From there, the argument fell out, so it was just took a bit of tinkering with things.

Comment: I found that it does not work for the case when $a=2$ because there is nothing to permute. Also, I think that it is not necessary to permute all numbers between $na$ and $(n+1)a$. It is enough to interchange $x=qa + r$ with $y=qa + s $, where $r,s$ are non-zero , $b=r mod a $and $r,s$ are distinct. For the case when $a=2$, I fix all the even numbers and add $2$ to each odd number.

Comment: @Minus22: good points. Yes, that should work for $a = 2$.